# Why some ransomware adds padding to headers

Tags: malware, file-encryption, ransomware, header

Does anyone know why some ransomware families (e.g. Cuba but also Phobos if I am not mistaken) pad the file header to get to 1024 bytes?

I mean what would be a reason for the ransomware developer to not just encrypt the entire file but add padding to get to a certain header size?

Source [elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co/security-labs/cuba-ransomware-malware-analysis):

> Before encrypting a file, Cuba ransomware prepends a 1024 byte header,
> the first 256 bytes are the string FIDEL.CA and some DWORD bytes
> values, the next 512 bytes are the encrypted ChaCha20 KEY/IV with the
> public RSA key and the rest is padded with 0.

I get why they add the `FIDEL.CA` flag and the key, but why add the additional padding? What's important about the header being 1024 bytes?

[image]

Comment: I think you might kick yourself for not thinking of the answer yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so that the ***decryption*** process knows where to start. If the added header was of a variable length, how would the decryption process know where to remove the added header and where to start decrypting? Without a pre-established header length, the actual header length would have to be recorded somewhere.

So, with a standard header length, the decryption process becomes straightforward: take the first 1024 bytes, check for the flag, grab the key, decrypt the rest of the file.

Yes, other methods could be used, like delimiters, but a pre-established header length is a perfectly fine design pattern to use.

Comment: Thank you and this makes perfectly sense (Indeed I will kick myself :) but just one more question, is there a reason why it´s 1024 bytes? why not 512 for example? I would guess that it´s because it represents exactly 1kB, 1 cluster on default in NTFS?

Comment: Or, it needs to allow for different key lengths and room for any other data they might want to include

Comment: @Questions123: Default NTFS cluster size on disks up to 16TB is 4K, not 1K. See [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat-9772e6f1-e31a-00d7-e18f-73169155af95).